# Как можно прокинуть данные из store в createApi?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с которой не могу справиться, я в функции UserToken создал переменную userToken и положил туда данные из store, как можно эту переменную userToken прокинуть в api в idToken:'',

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

 export function UserToken(props){
 ???? let userToken = useSelector((state) => state.user.token) ????
  return userToken
}

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "YogaApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl:
      "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update?key=AIzaSyD0Y0SlGB8NLbUylBAF7-VNn0FIIIs53m4",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getByName: builder.query({
      query: () => `${''}`,
    }),
    emailChange: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: "",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
        idToken: '????????' ,
          email: "hak@mail.ru",
          returnSecureToken: true,
        },
      }),      
    }),    
  }),
});
export const { useGetByNameQuery, useEmailChangeMutation } = api;
```

Comment: А что будет, если вы напишите `UserToken()`?

Comment: Тогда в IdToken попадает результат выполнения этой функции.

Comment: Так результат выполнения функции - `userToken`,  то что вам и надо :)